# Conventions for joins in Entity Framework 6.1.0 Code First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I believe my question is simple (not sure if the answer is as well):

Does anybody know how to force Entity Framework to use "INNER JOIN" as default convention, instead of "LEFT OUTER JOIN"?

Comment: afaik entity framework uses inner join by default. left outer join requires an "into" keyword.

Comment: to be honest, i have made some tests and it's using "left outer join" by default.

Comment: A tool like linq pad will show you the sql that's being generated by your query. When I join one table to another, the sql shows "inner join". What kind of test have you performed?

Comment: Can you show us the query you are trying to execute?

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to enforce inner or outer joins explicitly you can always use the `Join` or `GroupJoin` methods, respectively. (Or the comprehensive equivalents `join` and `join ... into`).

But, generally speaking, in LINQ statements you should avoid using explicit join statements. Use **navigation properties** instead. Navigation properties are the **associations** that have been defined between entities. Querying by navigation properties is querying by joins without hand-coding them. But when will these joins be inner or outer?

Take these three simple classes:

```
class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public int? PhotoId { get; set; }
    public Photo Photo { get; set; }
}

class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

class Photo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

What will happen if we query products including their categories and photos?

```
context.Products.Include(p => p.Category).Include(p => p.Photo)
```

Entity Framework looks at the *cardinality* of an association to determine whether it can generate the preferable inner join, or else an outer join:

- A required association generates an inner join.
- An optional association generates an outer join.

So in this case it will generate an inner join between `Product` and `Category` and an outer join between `Product` and `Photo`.

I think this is a sensible choice. It would be unexpected behaviour if including photos in the result set would suddenly reduce the number of fetched items.

The same applies to other query shapes, like

```
context.Products.Select(p => new { p.Name, Cat = p.Category.Name })
```

This generates an inner join.

```
context.Products.Select(p => new { p.Name, Cat = p.Photo.Image })
```

This generates an outer join.

EF isn't smart enough (yet?) to see that it could generate an inner join if in the latter example you'd only query products where `Photo != null`. That could be a case where you'd want to write an explicit LINQ join.

### Conclusion

So this focus on navigation properties shifts your attention from...

> how to force Entity Framework to use "INNER JOIN"

...to more business-logic related decisions whether associations should be required or optional.

Answer (score 1):

The `join` clause produces `Inner join` by default.

```
from x in table1
join y in table2 on x.id equals y.id
```

To make it act as outer join, you'd use `DefaultIfEmpty` method like this:

```
from x in table1
join y in table2 on x.id equals y.id into jointable
from z in jointable.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

If you add the query you are executing to your question, we can figure out why does `Left Outer Join` gets generated.

Here's nice resource explaining things: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx